# Calculating average overall score of assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x

grades.txt:

```
Q1 Q2 HW MT F
70 67 85 92 75
80 76 90 86 88
60 82 45 71 68
88 92 77 64 80
100 97 100 92 85
74 51 62 43 79
```

weights.txt:

```
Q1 Q2 HW MT F
--------------
10 10 15 30 35
```

Hello, it says that "calculate and display the average overall score. The overall score can be found by multiplying the weights of the assessments by the average score for each assesssment."

I calculate the average score for each assessment:

```
[78.66666667 77.5        76.5        74.66666667 79.16666667]
```

and converted weights to decimal place:

```
[0.1  0.1  0.15 0.3  0.35]
```

To calculate average overall score, I write this:

```
overall_score=sum(average_score*weights)
print(overall_score)
```

---

```
Output: 77.2
```

I got confused because it says calculate "average" overall score, not overall score itself. Briefly, I don't understand the difference between overall score and average overall score. So, do I need to make additional calculations or does my calculation give average overall score as well?

Comment: This isn't stack overflow related. You should clarify program goal with your teacher. FWIW sounds like overall score is similar to final grade given respective weights.

Answer (score 0):

By average overall score, from my understanding, you must calculate the weighted average for every line, and, then you must calculate average of all overall scores.
Overall score -> weighted average for every line
Average overall score -> average of the overall scores for every given line

E.g.:

Data

### Q1 Q2 HW MT F

10 10 10 10 10
5  5  5  5  5

Weights:

### Q1 Q2 HW MT F

10 10 15 30 35

Then, weighted average for line 1 must be 10, and for line 2 is 5.
Then, average for all overall score is (10+5)/2 = 7.5